# Replacing the array of ng-repeat causes weird re-rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got my ng-repeat set up like this:

```
.col-1-3 ng-repeat='profile in profiles track by $index'
```

On a certain event I want the profiles shown replaced by a new set of profiles. This is how it's done in the controller:

```
$scope.$apply( function() {
  $scope.profiles = $scope.nextProfiles
})
```

Now the thing is that for around 500ms instead of replacing the profiles, it is concatenating them. Just after these 500ms the array is finally replaced correctly.

Comment: Any CSS transitions involved?

Comment: create a demo that replicates this

Comment: @tasseKATT Yes it is. How does this break ng-repeat?
Edit: Even if I remove the css transitions it is happening

Comment: If you are using ngAnimate and ng-leave the old elements will have their transition played before being removed from the DOM, while the new will be added instantly. But since you are using `track by $index` this shouldn't really happen, so not sure.

Comment: I'm not even using ng-animate but my own transitions for that

Comment: You know what.. It actually is ng-animates fault. I haven't any rules for ng-enter/move defined. After I removed ng-animate from the app modules it worked flawlessly. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use ng-cloak to hide these transformations before they are rendered.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak for more details on this.